# Electron disable CTRL+A keyboard Shortcut

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I would like to disable shortcut "CTRL+A" on specific window,

Here is my current code based on [Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts)

```
electronLocalshortcut.register(app..main, 'Ctrl+A', () => {
   console.log('prevent ctrl+a');
});
```

I'm able to catch "CTRL+A" event but I'm not able to prevent select all effect it still select all items on the page, app bar etc

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` dosn't work ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Nope it does not work

Answer (score 1):

In your renderer (window) process, add a `keydown` listener, it will allow you to prevent any shortcuts you want:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler)

function keyDownHandler (event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.code === 'KeyA') {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
}
```